# magento check if a attribute is read only

Tags: php, magento

I have several store views on my magento,and I write a php file to change all product descriptions ,what i want is that if description on a store view "use default value" then it should not be changed,how can i check if it is set "use default value" before change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can switch store programatically and then compare its value with default value. Like following code.

```
$defaultDescription = $product->getDescription();
$storeDescription = $product->setStoreId(2)->getDescription();
if($defaultDescription != $storeDescription){
    // Update product description
}
```